# Clojure when is an apostrophe needed before vector

Tags: clojure, apostrophe

from "The Joy of Clojure" book:

first example:

```
(def fifth (comp first rest rest rest rest))
(fifth [1 2 3 4 5])
;=> e
```

second example:

```
(defn fnth [n]
  (apply comp
    (cons first
      (take (dec n) (repeat rest)))))
((fnth 5) '[a b c d e])
;=> e
```

why in the second example (but not in the first) do I need an apostrophe? without one the second example will raise an error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the second example you have to use apostrophe because you want to prevent evaluation of elements of the vector. If you remove the apostrophe, Clojure will try to resolve symbols `a`, `b`, etc., as as if they're bound to some values.

Example:

```
user> '[a b c d e]
;; => [a b c d e]
user> [a b c d e]
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: a
user> (let [a 1
            b 2
            c 3
            d 4
            e 5]
        [a b c d e])
;; => [1 2 3 4 5]
```

Please note that you don't have to use aphostrophe with numbers, since they evaluate to themselves:

```
user> 1
;; => 1
user> 2
;; => 2
user> [1 2 3]
;; => [1 2 3]
```

while symbols do not, Clojure will search for a value that given symbol is bound to:

```
user> x
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: x
```

So knowing this info and the fact that arguments of a function are evaluated before getting into the function, it should be clear why and when to use an apostrophe before a vector.

Answer (score 3):

In the second example the quote `'` is there to prevent the evaluator from evaluating the form after it (the vector).

The symbols in it aren't self-evaluating (read more here http://clojure.org/evaluation) and the evaluator would try to resolve them.

E. g.

```
(def foo 42)

[foo]
=> [42] ;; vector with number 42, resolved via foo

'[foo]
=> [foo] ;; vector with the symbol foo, decoupled from the var foo
```

You may want to read another `quote` example here http://clojure.org/special_forms#quote, and dig deeper to learn about the reader and syntax quotation here: http://clojure.org/reader